# Itext Android PDF cell size issue with Html

Tags: android, html, pdf, itext

Facing a problem while generating pdf from html template using Itext in android.
Have used com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.10 & com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10.

The problem is, itext create every cell of same size in pdf but in html cell size is different.

also tried size in px instead of percentage, but no luck.

**HTML**

```html
<table style="width: 100%; border: inherit; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%;  background-color: #bc8f8f; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; height: 30px" colspan="6"><b>Header</b></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 33%;"><b>Header</b></td>
        <td style="width: 45%;"><b>Description</b></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Time</b></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Qty.</b></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Price</b></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Total</b></td>
    </tr>
    REPLACE_VALUE
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td><b>Total :</b> </td><td>PLH__GRAND_TOTAL</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**REPLACE_VALUE** in above html will get replaced by the generated html code which is same as

```html
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 33%;"><b>Header</b></td>
            <td style="width: 45%;"><b>Description</b></td>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Time</b></td>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Qty.</b></td>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Price</b></td>
            <td style="width: 5%;"><b>Total</b></td>
        </tr>
```

Android JAVA Code

```
 Document document = new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(896, PageSize.A3.getHeight()), 36, 36, 36, 36);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(resultFile));

    // step 3
    document.open();

    CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true);

    // HTML
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    htmlContext.setImageProvider(new Base64ImageProvider());

    // Pipelines
    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new FileInputStream(activity.getCacheDir() + "/" + HTML_CACHE));

    // step 5
    document.close();
```